# Class that contains a list of itself

Tags: c++, class, c++11, standard-library

This is what I am trying to do (in my header file):

```
#include <forward_list>

class Data {
public:
        Data(int type, union data value);
        int which_type();
        void set_int(const int& i);
        void set_list(std::forward_list<Data*>& l);
        int get_int();
        std::forward_list<Data*>* get_list();
private:
        union data actual_data;
        int type;
};

union data {
        int i;
        std::forward_list<Data*> l;
};
```

If everything were to work properly, this would create a class which could contain an integer or a list, and it would be as type-safe as possible because I would call the which_type function before every call to one of the get functions, and the get functions would throw an exception if the object isn't the correct type.

However, this isn't possible because `Data` needs a `union data`, and `union data` needs a `forward_list<Data*>`. I believe boost has what I am looking for, but is there a way to do this without boost? I would just rather use the standard library in order to learn more about the c++ standard library.

Comment: Why not forward declare `Data` and move `union_data` before `Data`'s definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to forward declare the `class Data` and then declare the `union data` before the `class Data` proper declaration.

```
#include <forward_list>


class Data;
union data {
        int i;
        std::forward_list<Data*> l;
};


class Data {
public:
        Data(int type, union data value);
        int which_type();
        void set_int(const int& i);
        void set_list(std::forward_list<Data*>& l);
        int get_int();
        std::forward_list<Data*>* get_list();
private:
        union data actual_data;
        int type;
};
```

Compiles with g++ and clang++ with no problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I did not know that c++ could do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Class members may not be incomplete class types (although they may be pointers or references to such types). So you need to define `union data` before you can declare a member of this type in `Data`. This is straightforward:

```
class Data {
public:
        Data(int type, union data value);
        int which_type();
        void set_int(const int& i);
        void set_list(std::forward_list<Data*>& l);
        int get_int();
        std::forward_list<Data*>* get_list();
private:
        union data {
            int i;
            std::forward_list<Data*> l;
        } actual_data;
        int type;
};
```

Another solution is to define the union *first,* since it doesn't need the `Data` class to be complete, since it only uses a pointer to it.

```
union data {
    int i;
    std::forward_list<class Data*> l;
};

class Data {
public:
        Data(int type, union data value);
        int which_type();
        void set_int(const int& i);
        void set_list(std::forward_list<Data*>& l);
        int get_int();
        std::forward_list<Data*>* get_list();
private:
        data actual_data;
        int type;
};
```

Comment: This does not work, I tried it. It does need the Data even if it is just a pointer.

Comment: I'm getting all kinds of other errors right now, so I'll let you know once I've resolved those.

Comment: okay, when I try your second suggestion (the first probably works but I haven't tried), I get an error: `error: 'Data' was not declared in this scope
  std::forward_list<Data*>* l;`

Comment: Actually, I see now the difference between your and my code. I used `Data*` instead of `class Data*` in the union definition. Sorry.